# Taylor approximation is different from the actual value

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

The problem is to use the $n$th Taylor polynomial to approximate the value of $F(x)=x^{2}\cos{x}$ with $n=3,x_{0}=-2,x=-1.09$.

I found that the $3$rd Taylor polynomial with remainder term is \begin{align*}
x^{2}\cos{x} =& 4\cos(2)+[-4\cos(2)+4\sin(2)][x+2]+[-\cos(2)-4\sin(2)][x+2]^{2}+ \\ 
& [2\cos(2)+  \dfrac{1}{3}\sin(2)][x+2]^{3} + [\dfrac{(x+2)^{4}}{24}][-8\cos(\xi(x))+16\sin(\xi(x))]
\end{align*}

approximating $x=-1.09$ using the Taylor polynomial,

\begin{align*}
(-1.09)^{2}\cos(-1.09) =& 4\cos(2)+[-4\cos(2)+4\sin(2)][(-1.09)+2]+[-\cos(2)-4\sin(2)][(-1.09)+2]^{2}+ \\ 
& [2\cos(2)+  \dfrac{1}{3}\sin(2)][(-1.09)+2]^{3} + [\dfrac{((-1.09)+2)^{4}}{24}][-8\cos(\xi(x))+16\sin(\xi(x))]  \\
=& 0.0938985 + [\dfrac{((0.91)^{4}}{24}][-8\cos(\xi(x))+16\sin(\xi(x))]
\end{align*}

However, $(-1.09)^{2}\cos(-1.09)=0.549479$ which is a lot of decimals different from Taylor approximation of $0.0938985$.

Is there something that I miss?

Comment: Note that the remainder term has size of about $1$, $\frac{\sqrt3}3$ with some effort, so that an error of $0.5$ is not that surprising.

Comment: I see. Thanks. What would be the upper bound for the truncation error?

Comment: That depends on how you bound $x$. Without any bounds you get with Cauchy-Schwarz $|−8\cos(ξ)+16\sin(ξ)|\le 8\sqrt{1+2^2}\sqrt{\cos^2(ξ)+\sin^2(ξ)}$, so that the correct refined bound on the coefficient from above is $\sqrt{5}/3<0.75$. Thus the error is bounded by $\frac34|x+2|^4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This just means that teh third order is not sufficient in particular because $-1.09$ is very far away from $-2$.

To make the story short, what you have is
$$x^2 \cos(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(-n^2+n+4\right) \cos \left(2-\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)+4 n \sin   \left(2-\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)}{n!}(x+2)^n$$ So, if you truncate to $O((x+2)^{p+1})$ you will have the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 0.4926841712 \\
 3 & 0.0938985194 \\
 4 & 0.6047229336 \\
 5 & 0.5723469909 \\
 6 & 0.5466012534 \\
 7 & 0.5489493571 \\
 8 & 0.5495411050 \\
 9 & 0.5494858556 \\
 10 & 0.5494781119 \\
 11 & 0.5494788050 \\
 12 & 0.5494788702 \\
 13 & 0.5494788647 \\
 14 & 0.5494788644
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Expand just the cosine series around $x=-2$ and you will have:
$$x^2cos x = x^2\left(cos(2) + sin(2)[x+2] - \frac{cos(2)[x+2]^2}{2} - \frac{sin(2)[x+2]^3}{6}\right )$$
$$\\$$
(Expanding the $x^2$ in a Taylor polynomial and multiplying everything by brute force also works, but the Taylor series for $x^2$ will just reduce back to $x^2$ anyway, so it is not necessary)

$$\\$$
Evaluated at $x=-1.09$:

$$ (-1.09)^2cos(-1.09) \approx 0.549479$$
$$\\$$
$$(-1.09)^2\left(cos(2) + sin(2)[0.91] - \frac{cos(2)[0.91]^2}{2} - \frac{sin(2)[0.91]^3}{6}\right )\approx 0.557713$$

Comment: But this way you do not get the same Taylor polynomials of the given function. This would be correct if the task was to just efficiently evaluate the function using Taylor series given that the exact values of $\cos2$ and $\sin2$ were provided from somewhere else.

Comment: I see your point and appreciate feedback. But in Claude's answer, there are terms of $cos(2-\frac{n\pi}{2})$ and and $sin(2-\frac{n\pi}{2})$. Isn't that the same thing? Don't the exact values of these also have to be proveded from somewhere else?

Comment: Now I'm not complaining, but the question asked for n=3 and it seems Claude had to use more terms than that to come farily close.

Comment: One might even wonder, 4 upvotes at the moment, Is it just to throw in my face that I did such a bad job?

Comment: You did not a bad job, you just solve a different, modified task. Writing $\sin(x+\frac{n\pi}2)$ is just a short form for writing the sequence of derivatives $\sin x,\,\cos x,\,-\sin x,\,-\cos x,\,\sin x,...$, all using the same numerical values, just with different signs.

Comment: But why is it Ok in Claude's answer to contain cos(2) and sin(2) whereas in mine it isnt?

Comment: Where do you see that taken at fault? In your product you just contain some terms that a degree 3 truncation of the whole expression would not contain. Conversely, in the correct answer to the given task these apparently important terms are all contained from degree 5 onwards, reflecting the start of the appearance of correct digits.

Comment: Ok, and my solution is in its full expanded form is actually also a 5th degree. That is not the issue. His answer is not very different from mine if you really expand it, i just did it faster and shorter. What I don't understand is why you said cos(2) and sin(2) can't be part of it, because "the exact values have to be provided form somewhere else", but in his answer it is OK to contain cos(2) and sin(2)

Comment: If you have an accurate cosine function available, the task makes no sense. So imagine yourself on an isolated island, you only have a stone tablet available on which the values of $\cos2$ and $\sin2$ are engraved, and for some ineffable reason you need to compute $f(-1.09)$. As I said, your approach is more efficient, but it is not the task in the question.

Comment: And no, your formula expanded is not the original task Tayor polynomial of degree 5, as it would be missing the terms stemming from the degree 4 and 5 terms of the series of the cosine factor.

Comment: Received the "extended discussion" remark so my final word: Claude has to have the same stone tablet available, but that's somehow ok, but for me it isn't

Comment: Think about the product as a rectangular scheme, one axis the terms of the first factor, the other of the second. Inside the scheme are the products of the axis terms. Products of the same degree are located on anti-diagonals. **o** What you do is sum over a square of 3 terms on each side. **o** What the task demands is to sum over the triangle bounded by the anti-diagonal of degree 3. **o** The 3-square is contained in the 5-triangle, but does not fill it completely.

Comment: Ok, I don't dispute that, and thanks for clearing it out for me (not being sarcastic). What I dispute is that I can't have cos(2) and sin(2) because they are exact values, but he gets to have it. Thank you and have a nice day!